# How to build a distributed robust linked list on several computers on the net?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, distributed, robustness

I was thinking about building a program that use a raid(disk) like algorithms. If one computer dies. The next will step in. In it's place. And it need to scale from 1 - 1000 computers.

I need some advice.

What the name of the algorithms I'm need to learn?

At one point I thought it was possible to build it on top of git.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to read this [paper](http://labs.google.com/papers/gfs.html) on the Google File System. From the abstract:

> We have designed and implemented the Google File System, a scalable distributed file system for large distributed data-intensive applications. It provides fault tolerance while running on inexpensive commodity hardware, and it delivers high aggregate performance to a large number of clients.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com). It has distributed implementation of Set, List and more. Hazelcast is an open source transactional, distributed/partitioned implementation of queue, topic, map, set, list, lock and executor service. It is super easy to work with; just add hazelcast.jar into your classpath and start coding. Almost no configuration is required.

Hazelcast is released under Apache license and enterprise grade support is also available. Code is hosted at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/hazelcast/).

Comment: Could you provide links ? I found the List (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/list.html) , but "Hazelcast List cannot be scaled beyond the capacity of a single machine.". Or are you talking about something else ?

Answer (score 1):

[Distributed hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table) pop into my mind...

Answer (score 1):

I've seen both Hadoop and the Google File System mentioned, but nobody has specifically mentioned [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/core/docs/r0.19.1/hdfs_design.html) - the distributed filesystem that comes with Hadoop.  You can set the desired level of redundancy, and lose the occasional node without losing your data.

One caveat: You need to make sure the one machine that holds the "namenode" (the master machine and single point of failure in an HDFS cluster) is solid - RAID mirroring, backups, the works.  You lose the namenode, you lose the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out the [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) algorithm. It's a relatively simple way of getting high scalability, that doesn't force the algorithm designer to think about locking, communication, etc. There are several implementations available, for example the open-source [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) by the Apache foundation.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use distributed locks/mutexes as in:

A sqrt(N) Algorithm for Mutual Exclusion in Decentralized Systems, by Maekawa: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=214445

On the performance of distributed lock-based synchronization, by Lubowich and Taubenfeld: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1946155

2) Or you can use lock-free linked lists as in:

Lock-Free Linked Lists and Skip Lists, by  Fomitchev 
 and Rupert: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~ruppert/papers/lfll.pdf

Lock-free linked lists using compare-and-swap, by Valois: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=224988

Answer (score -1):

BitTorrent?  :)

Comment: Actually, you probably could build a distributed storage system over BitTorrent, so it was only partially a joke.

Comment: Yea. As I understand it. It is the trackers that need to be distributed. And everyone need to share there IP for some time. So we can shelter the Heroes that support the system the most.

Answer (score -1):

You could build something like [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/). Each hash entry could be a file block (e.g. SHA hash of block to contents).

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out [Appistry EAF](http://www.appistry.com).  Its a distributed execution platform.  It handles all the failover of tasks for you, so you don't have to build that into your code.  If one node fails, another node automatically takes over.  And unlike Grid, there is no centralized controller, to you remove the single point of failure/bottleneck of those types of solutions.

There is a free download available up to 5 machines.